# Set Asp.Net Core MVC Json options

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, .net-core, json.net

One of the classes that I have in my project called, say, `AC`,  has a property `Address` that is of type `IPEndPoint`. This type, as well as `IPAddress`, are notorious for not being serializable to JSON by default. Since I needed to serialize my class, I implemented two custom converters: `IPAddressConverter` and `IPEndPointConverter`. To make Newtonsoft use these two converters, I made this class:

```
public sealed class CustomSettings : JsonSerializerSettings
{
    public CustomSettings() : base()
    {
        this.Converters.Add(new IPAddressConverter());
        this.Converters.Add(new IPEndPointConverter());
        this.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto;
    }
}
```

..which I use in my `Main` like so:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => new CustomSettings();
```

Now I am trying to add an API to my program. I have created a .Net Core Web API project and have integrated it into my program successfully. However, problems arose when I attempted to write a POST method that required an instance of `AC` in JSON form from the request body. The serializer couldn't convert the `IPEndPoint`, and thus the value of `AC` was always `null`.

Information regarding configuration of .Net Core APIs is pretty sparse. Can anyone tell me how I can pass those same settings to the MVC's serializer?

**EDIT**

I found a way (sort of). Turns out you can set the JSON options in the `ConfigureServices` method.

I attempted to modify the MVC's serializer's settings the same way I did for the rest of my program by doing this:

```
services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options => options.SerializerSettings = new CustomSettings());
```

However, this doesn't work as `options.SerializerSettings` is read only.

I *could* pass the converters one by one, but I'd prefer if they were all managed from one place (the `CustomSettings` class). Is this possible?

Comment: Or create an extension method that does it for you in one place, which is what i settled on

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Create an extension method that encapsulates what it is you want configured

```
public static void AddCustomSettings(this Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings settings) {
    settings.Converters.Add(new IPAddressConverter());
    settings.Converters.Add(new IPEndPointConverter());
    settings.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto;
}
```

And configure it in `ConfigureServices`

```
services.AddJsonOptions(options => options.SerializerSettings.AddCustomSettings());
```

Comment: And on what do I call this method in the other project's `Main`? (Instead of doing `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => new CustomSettings();`)

Comment: @Sty, The extension is for setting up the API what you have for main can remain the same